# Segmentation fault with valgrind on std::to_string() call after compiling on linux with GCC. Application works fine with clang on OSX

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I am working on a cross platform network proxy written in C++. The application is currently stable on OSX when compiled with Clang using CMake, I have successfully compiled the source on Fedora using CMake and GCC however when running the application I am getting a segmentation fault which I can't work out. Below is the valgrind output for the segmentation fault.

```
==18== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==18==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==18==    at 0x4840613: memmove (vg_replace_strmem.c:1270)
==18==    by 0x4E4275F: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==18==    by 0x413EB2: process_request_headers(session_t&, packet_type, int, bool) (parser.cpp:492)
==18==    by 0x412B49: handle_http_request_data(packet_type, int, long long, char const*, unsigned long, session_t*) (parser.cpp:206)
==18==    by 0x41CE9F: proxy_http(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, long long, thread_info_t*) (proxy.cpp:284)
==18==    by 0x420743: accept_request(void*) (proxy.cpp:904)
==18==    by 0x50533F8: start_thread (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.32.so)
==18==    by 0x516DB52: clone (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.32.so)
==18==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==18==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==18==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==18==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==18==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

In parser.cpp:492 there is a call to std::to_string() and I have no idea why this appears to cause the failure. I will admit I am pretty new to valgrind so I am unsure if I am interpreting this output correctly. Could the problem be in the version of C++ I'm using maybe? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say anything without a [mcve]. Are you sure you don't have UB somewhere?

Comment: Up until the segmentation fault everything looks good when tested side by side with the Darwin build.

Comment: The likelihood of a bug in STL is pretty low compared to your code. `operator=` means that you are likely moving from a corrupted source. Maybe the object containing the source `std::string` is nullptr? Or dead? If you can, compile the code with sanitizers and see what they print. In my experience they can the errors earlier with more meaningful messages.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok! So I seem to have found the issue, the above suggestions of UB and nullptr type issues lead me to an investigation where I found the issue. The call to std::to_string() was being assigned to a struct member (of std::string) however earlier in the code the structure had been subject to to a howler of a memset() which obviously destroyed the internal state or function pointers of the STL type. Harsh lesson learned.